# UdpClient.Close() throwing android.os.DeadObjectException in Unity (with IL2CPP)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, udpclient, il2cpp, deadobjectexception

I switched my Unity project from MONO to IL2CPP. Then it began to crash.
I found the source of the bug - calling UdpClient.Close() function.
This causes Android builds to freeze + crash.

The log cat logs shows the following:

```
 storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
08-18 14:24:36.551  1509  2246 E Watchdog: !@Sync 17064 [2019-08-18 14:24:36.550] FD count : 942
08-18 14:24:37.840  1509  1991 E InputDispatcher: channel '24dfab2 com.touchupstudios.CandyLand/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-18 14:24:37.854   696   696 E HWComposer: presentAndGetReleaseFences: present failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
08-18 14:24:37.867   696   696 E HWComposer: presentAndGetReleaseFences: present failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
08-18 14:24:37.880   696   696 E HWComposer: presentAndGetReleaseFences: present failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
08-18 14:24:37.888  1509  3574 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-18 14:24:37.895   696   764 E SurfaceFlinger: size mismatch (2220, 1080) > (1080, 2220)
08-18 14:24:37.896   696   696 E HWComposer: presentAndGetReleaseFences: present failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{24dfab2 u0 com.touchupstudios.CandyLand/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1143)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:500)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3889)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5441)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
08-18 14:24:37.967  1509  1588 E WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
08-18 14:24:38.076 14946 15012 E PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[65734769308427719] not persisted.
08-18 14:24:40.152  5204  5329 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 10, reportDelayMillis=0
08-18 14:24:41.664  5204 18050 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 10
08-18 14:24:41.674  5204  5329 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 10, reportDelayMillis=0
```

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] - Updated everything (Unity and Firebase) to latest version and the error disappeared.